# how to push data or message from sql server to web application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a **asp.net MVC 3** web application project. The project is simple, it provides a web page listing stored procedures in SQL Server. when user selects a stored procedure and hit "run" button, it is invoked to execute in SQL Server and return some execution result.

My stored procedure is logically divided into several steps, say 10 steps, each step prints a message like `step 1: doing A...`, `step2: dong B...`, until `step 10: done` or `step 10: fail. (with error message)`.

I don't want the user just hang on to wait until stored procedure finishes and just see the final result message. I want them to see some kind of live execution of stored procedure, so that user is well updated of where the stored procedure is.Some stored procedures are quick and take few seconds to finish, some are very slow and take even 1 hour to finish.

**Now the question is:** how could I push theses step messages from SQL Server to web application, so that in web browser, user can see each step message get printed in real-time fashion?

I search lots of info, the best i can see is model controller notifies view once there's change in model, but still need model controller to pull from SQL Server, I don't see any real push from SQL Server to web application. Your advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a log table at the start of the procedure, with a unique name.  The MVC code would display a grid or other element showing this log table, the stored procedure would simply add rows to the table after each step is complete...

1. Grab the session ID of the connection
2. The procedure creates a file called LOG_SessID
3. The MVC opens the table and uses the Meta Refresh or a Timer to redisplay the page
4. Each redisplay checks to see if the table still exists, if not, it
   assumes the procedure is done and prints the appropriate message

Comment: Thanks Sparky. I did similar funtion as in your step 1&2. I output the messages into a table, the messages are to be kept for historical reference, the table inlcude 3 columns: msg_ID, msg, SP_ID.
Your step 3 & 4 is sth. like having a client script to auto refresh web page in predefined time interval, each refresh will poll table to see if there's any new message to display (pull data). This is still not desired. I don't want multiple users to poll the message table, this will keep sql server busy. Further more, stored procedures take much different time to complete.

Comment: Although there's notify mechanism from model to view to cause a push refresh, this is still within the web application itself. My target is that web application receives message only when database has update, in aother words, database can notify web application when it has update. For the rest of time, web application just wait. 
My target is similar to socket listener in TCP/IP programming, where a socket listener will be notified when there's incoming tcp/ip data from another application. This is accomplished by certain service of windows. Hope I clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be that you break your SP into steps and call each Step's SP and update the User screen (even have separate MVC VIEWS/PARTIAL VIEWS for each step's success and failure) based on the result!